# Android API 28 Pattern.compile always throwing exception

Tags: android

```
String pattern = "\\{(*.)\\{";
Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("Some string");
```

Crashes with illegal state exception.

When I browse source code of Pattern class, method compile , it has only one statement i.e throw statement. And return runtime exception

Is Mean that android blocked Pattern class. If it is,  is there any otherway of using Pattern class of java regex

Comment: The code `Patter.complile("\{(*.)\{").matcher("some string”)` doesn't compile, could you put in the code that does and still causes the error?

Comment: I think it was typo mistake, it is Pattern not Patter

Comment: @KrishnaSharma yep, i suspected as much, but then `complile` should be `compile` and the argument to `compile` contains an illegal escape character. So we can't get too far reverse engineering the typos, just better for @ramesh-penta to put in the code that he's managed to get compiling then throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Agreed `String pattern = "\\{(*.)\\{";
Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher("Some string");`

Comment: Issue is with regular express **\\{(*.)\\{**

Comment: Issue is with your regular expression `\\{(*.)\\{` 
Let us know what are you trying do

Comment: typo error it is  .*  in brackets. Tested .it is working  as a simple java program. Issue is with android api 28. Throwing exception irrespective of the arguments of compile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I browse source code of Pattern class, method compile , it has
>   only one statement i.e throw statement. And return runtime exception

Because you haven't downloaded source code of Android API 28 yet. You should go to download it in `SDK Manager` then restart IDE you will see the full source code.

**Root cause:** Your pattern **is not a valid regex in Java and Android** as well
**Solution 1:** Change regex to

```
String pattern = "\\{(.*)\\{";
```

**Solution 2:** If you want to add "(" or ")" in your regex you must use "\\" before that

```
String pattern = "\\{\\(*.\\)\\{";
```

**Bonus:** Refer [this](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) link to learn more about regex.

**Update 1:** Based on your example, I guess you want to get the value inside curly braces

```
String title = "Not your billing ZIP code? {Update your address on file.}";

String pattern = ".*\\{(.*)\\}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(title);
if (matcher.matches()) {
       Log.d("regex_test", matcher.group(0));
       Log.d("regex_test", matcher.group(1));
} else {
       Log.d("regex_test", "not match");
}
```

**The output:**

```
08-13 15:26:12.132 6516-6516/com.example.pc.myapplication D/regex_test: Not your billing ZIP code? {Update your address on file.}
08-13 15:26:12.132 6516-6516/com.example.pc.myapplication D/regex_test: Update your address on file.
```

Comment: installed API 28. now compile method not throwing exception. but there is an error in importing following packages in Pattern class. dalvik.annotation.optimization.ReachabilitySensitive libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry;

Comment: Do not care about missing import error in Pattern class. The problem is your regex is not valid. Have you tried the link I give above?

Comment: this piece of code working in Java but not working in Android:  Crashing at matcher.group(1) with message no matching groups found.   String title =  "Not your billing ZIP code? {Update your address on file.}";
      Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile("\\{(.*)\\}").matcher(title);          System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

Comment: Show me one (or 2, 3) examples that you want to match with your regex.

Comment: Thank you very much. the provided regex pattern is working to get the value inside curly braces.

Comment: Glad to hear that.